# How to change text by pressing FloatingActionButton?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to change the `main_text` in the first page by pressing the `FloatingActionButton` in another page, but the text didn't change.

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: Center(child: Text(main_text)),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Get.to(const new_page());
        setState(() {
          main_text = '';
        });
      },
      tooltip: 'Add Alarm',
     ),
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: please add a clear code

Comment: what do you have on `new_page`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to change data from one page that would change data in another page, you need to use `State Management`. There are multiple tutorial in Youtube.

For me when I started out, this was a little complex topic to understand. But eventually got hang of it.

You can use `Provider`, `Riverpod` or `BloC` to manage state in your app. Find these tutorials for your reference.

`Provider`: https://youtu.be/Mk3nsf3wTIs FOLLOWED BY  https://youtu.be/SRHkYKBClUI
`Bloc`: https://youtu.be/fIY3TU9ORZI and https://youtu.be/6PgYhvnCN58 FOLLOWED BY https://youtu.be/Ep6R7U9wa0U
`Riverpod`: https://youtu.be/U_9yhp0aSaQ FOLLOWED BY https://youtu.be/8H3bwxxla4Y or https://youtu.be/Zp7VKVhirmw

Download packages here, [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) , [BloC](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc), [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod)